# Read a file and creat a table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a help in a difficult mission.
I have more then 30.000 files in a especific folder (*\backup) in xl?? format and need to read the cell B4. I thought the better idea is use the VBA in Excel to read this specific cell for each file and write on a table A:B.

Comment: Thank you for the note attention on SO rules.
I'll do my best and returns with a specific problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following should help you, just remember to amend the declaration for the destination Worksheet name and the full path to the folder where the Workbooks you want to read reside.

The code below will loop through your desired Directory/Folder and read all the files with an .xls* extension, get the value from the first Worksheet in cell B4 and pass this value to the destination worksheet.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet: Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet where you want to aggregate the data.

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

myPath = "C:\backup\"
'set the full path to the folder you want to utilize, remember to add the last \

Last = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
If Last >= 2 Then wsDestination.Range("A2:B" & Last).ClearContents
'clear the destination worksheet ready to aggregate again

myExtension = "*.xls*"
'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")

myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
'Target Path with Ending Extention

Do While myFile <> ""
'Loop through each Excel file in folder
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    DoEvents
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
    wsDestination.Cells(1, "A").Value = "Filename"
    wsDestination.Cells(1, "B").Value = "Value From Cell B4"

    NextRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    wsDestination.Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = myFile
    wsDestination.Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("B4").Value
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    'Close Workbook without Saving
    DoEvents
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    myFile = Dir
    'Next File
Loop

MsgBox "Transfer of Data Completed!", vbInformation, "Info"
'Message Box when tasks are completed

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it returns an error on the "End If" above the "wb.Close SaveChanges:=False" informing there's no "IF" for the "END IF" in case

Comment: @PedroCornélio I've just updated my answer,.. try again pls :)

Comment: your code really helped a lot! I just need to do some modifications, but thanks a lot!